# Notifications not cancelling on action click android

Tags: android, android-notifications

When there is an app-level notification, I send out a notification to the user. Inside of the notification, I perform an action, where the call intent is done. The action takes place without any problem, but after clicking on the action, the notification doesn't cancel. I am not able to figure out why this is happening. I have set the autoCancel to true but still it doesnt work. Posting what I have tried so far.

**MapsFragment.java**

```
public PendingIntent createGeofencePendingIntent(int myRange) {
    Log.d(TAG, "createGeofencePendingIntent");

    if(myRange == 3) {
        final Intent intent3 = new Intent(getContext(), GeofenceTransitionService.class);
        intent3.putExtra("region", inString[2]);
        return geoFencePendingIntent3 = PendingIntent.getService(
                getContext(), 1, intent3, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

    }
    if(myRange == 1) {
        final Intent intent1 = new Intent(getContext(), GeofenceTransitionService.class);
        intent1.putExtra("region", inString[0]);
        return geoFencePendingIntent1 = PendingIntent.getService(
                getContext(), 2, intent1, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

    }

    if(myRange == 2) {
        final Intent intent2 = new Intent(getContext(), GeofenceTransitionService.class);
        intent2.putExtra("region", inString[1]);
        return geoFencePendingIntent2 = PendingIntent.getService(
                getContext(), 3, intent2, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

    }
    return null;
}
```

**GeofenceTransistionService.java**

```
public class GeofenceTransitionService extends IntentService {

private static final String TAG = GeofenceTransitionService.class.getSimpleName();

int counter = 0;
String geoFencingRegion;
public GeofenceTransitionService() {
    super(TAG);
}
String str;
boolean appNotifications;

DatabaseReference gPhone;
String guardianPhoneNumber;
String status;
String numberPlus;

@Override
protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {


    GeofencingEvent geofencingEvent = GeofencingEvent.fromIntent(intent);

    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
    String userId = sharedPreferences.getString(Preferences.USERID, "");
    appNotifications = sharedPreferences.getBoolean(getString(R.string.title_app_notifications_key), false);

    if(userId != null){
        gPhone = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("guardians").child("guardianEmails");
    }

    // Handling

    str = intent.getStringExtra("region");
    if ( geofencingEvent.hasError() ) {
        String errorMsg = getErrorString(geofencingEvent.getErrorCode() );
        Log.e( TAG, errorMsg );
        return;
    }
    if(str.matches("a")) {
        counter = 1;
        geoFencingRegion = " zone 1";
    }
    else if(str.matches("b")) {
        counter = 2;
        geoFencingRegion = " zone 2";
    }

    else if (str.matches("c")) {
        counter = 3;
        geoFencingRegion = " zone 3";
    }
    int geoFenceTransition = geofencingEvent.getGeofenceTransition();
    // Check if the transition type is of interest
    if ( geoFenceTransition == Geofence.GEOFENCE_TRANSITION_ENTER ||
            geoFenceTransition == Geofence.GEOFENCE_TRANSITION_EXIT ) {
        // Get the geofence that were triggered
        List<Geofence> triggeringGeofences = geofencingEvent.getTriggeringGeofences();

        String geofenceTransitionDetails = getGeofenceTrasitionDetails(geoFenceTransition, triggeringGeofences );

        // Send notification details as a String
        if(appNotifications) {
            sendNotification(geofenceTransitionDetails);
        }
    }
}


private String getGeofenceTrasitionDetails(int geoFenceTransition, List<Geofence> triggeringGeofences) {
    // get the ID of each geofence triggered
    ArrayList<String> triggeringGeofencesList = new ArrayList<>();
    for ( Geofence geofence : triggeringGeofences ) {
        triggeringGeofencesList.add( geofence.getRequestId() );
    }
    if ( geoFenceTransition == Geofence.GEOFENCE_TRANSITION_ENTER ) {
        status = "Entering " + geoFencingRegion;

    }
    else if ( geoFenceTransition == Geofence.GEOFENCE_TRANSITION_EXIT ) {
        status = "Exiting " + geoFencingRegion;
    }

    try {
            gPhone.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
                @Override
                public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                    LocationModel myModel = dataSnapshot.getValue(LocationModel.class);
                    if(myModel !=null){
                        guardianPhoneNumber = myModel.getGuardianNumber();
                        guardianPhoneNumber = guardianPhoneNumber.replaceAll("[^0-9]","");
                        numberPlus = "+1" + guardianPhoneNumber;
                        SmsManager smsManager = SmsManager.getDefault();
                        smsManager.sendTextMessage(numberPlus, null, "The standard user  is " + status, null, null);
                    }
                }

                @Override
                public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

                }
            });
       // Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "SMS Sent!",
             //   Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                "SMS faild, please try again later!",
                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return status + TextUtils.join( ", ", triggeringGeofencesList);
}

private void sendNotification( String msg ) {
    Log.i(TAG, "sendNotification: " + msg );

    // Intent to start the main Activity
    Intent notificationIntent = MainMenuActivity.makeNotificationIntent(getApplicationContext(), msg);
    notificationIntent.putExtra("Maps", "geofenceCall");

    TaskStackBuilder stackBuilder = TaskStackBuilder.create(this);
    stackBuilder.addParentStack(MainMenuActivity.class);
    stackBuilder.addNextIntent(notificationIntent);
    PendingIntent notificationPendingIntent = stackBuilder.getPendingIntent(counter, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

    // Creating and sending Notification
    NotificationManager notificatioMng =
            (NotificationManager) getSystemService( Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE );
    notificatioMng.notify(
            counter,
            createNotification(msg, notificationPendingIntent));
}

// Create notification
private Notification createNotification(String msg, PendingIntent notificationPendingIntent) {

    NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this);
    notificationBuilder
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_contact_phone_black_24dp)
            .setColor(Color.WHITE)
            .setAutoCancel(true)
            .setContentTitle("Geofence Alert!")
            .setContentText(msg + "Do you want to call the patient you are tracking?")
            .addAction(R.drawable.ic_call_black_24dp,"Call",notificationPendingIntent)
            .setContentIntent(notificationPendingIntent)
            .setDefaults(Notification.DEFAULT_LIGHTS | Notification.DEFAULT_VIBRATE | Notification.DEFAULT_SOUND);

    return notificationBuilder.build();
}


private static String getErrorString(int errorCode) {
    switch (errorCode) {
        case GeofenceStatusCodes.GEOFENCE_NOT_AVAILABLE:
            return "GeoFence not available";
        case GeofenceStatusCodes.GEOFENCE_TOO_MANY_GEOFENCES:
            return "Too many GeoFences";
        case GeofenceStatusCodes.GEOFENCE_TOO_MANY_PENDING_INTENTS:
            return "Too many pending intents";
        default:
            return "Unknown error.";
    }
}
}
```

**MainActivity.java**

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main_menu);
    ButterKnife.bind(this);


    String type = getIntent().getStringExtra("Maps");

    if (type != null) {
        switch (type) {
            case "mapsFragment":
                Fragment mapsFragment = new MapsFragment();
                FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.container_gaFragments, mapsFragment).commit();
                break;

            case "gasstation":
                Uri gmmIntentUri = Uri.parse("geo:0,0?q=gas station");
                Intent mapIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, gmmIntentUri);
                mapIntent.setPackage("com.google.android.apps.maps");
                startActivity(mapIntent);
                break;
            case "geofenceCall":
                databaseReferenceGuardian.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                        LocationModel locationModel = dataSnapshot.getValue(LocationModel.class);
                        if(locationModel !=null){
                            guardianNumber = locationModel.getGuardianNumber();
                            guardianNumber = guardianNumber.replaceAll("[^0-9]","");
                            numberPlus = "+1" + guardianNumber;
                            String uri = "tel:" + numberPlus;
                            //Build the intent that will make the phone call
                            Intent callIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL, Uri.parse(uri));
                            callIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                            if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(MainMenuActivity.this, Manifest.permission.CALL_PHONE) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                                // TODO: Consider calling
                                //    ActivityCompat#requestPermissions
                                // here to request the missing permissions, and then overriding
                                //   public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions,
                                //                                          int[] grantResults)
                                // to handle the case where the user grants the permission. See the documentation
                                // for ActivityCompat#requestPermissions for more details.
                                return;
                            }
                            getApplicationContext().startActivity(callIntent);
                        }

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

                    }
                });
        }
    }

public static Intent makeNotificationIntent(Context context, String msg) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(context, MainMenuActivity.class);
    intent.putExtra(NOTIFICATION_MSG, msg);
    return intent;
}
```

I am just posting the relevant code, which is necessary for creating the notification. Any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Notification will not be cancel when the user click on the action button.
you have to cancel it manually from your main activity...
put below code in your `MainActivity.java`:

```
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main_menu);
        ButterKnife.bind(this);


    NotificationManager notificatioMng =
            (NotificationManager) getSystemService( Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE );
notificatioMng.cancelAll();
//The above lines will cancel the notification

        String type = getIntent().getStringExtra("Maps");

        if (type != null) {
            switch (type) {
                case "mapsFragment":
                    Fragment mapsFragment = new MapsFragment();
                    FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                    fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.container_gaFragments, mapsFragment).commit();
                    break;

                case "gasstation":
                    Uri gmmIntentUri = Uri.parse("geo:0,0?q=gas station");
                    Intent mapIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, gmmIntentUri);
                    mapIntent.setPackage("com.google.android.apps.maps");
                    startActivity(mapIntent);
                    break;
                case "geofenceCall":
                    databaseReferenceGuardian.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                            LocationModel locationModel = dataSnapshot.getValue(LocationModel.class);
                            if(locationModel !=null){
                                guardianNumber = locationModel.getGuardianNumber();
                                guardianNumber = guardianNumber.replaceAll("[^0-9]","");
                                numberPlus = "+1" + guardianNumber;
                                String uri = "tel:" + numberPlus;
                                //Build the intent that will make the phone call
                                Intent callIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL, Uri.parse(uri));
                                callIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                                if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(MainMenuActivity.this, Manifest.permission.CALL_PHONE) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                                    // TODO: Consider calling
                                    //    ActivityCompat#requestPermissions
                                    // here to request the missing permissions, and then overriding
                                    //   public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions,
                                    //                                          int[] grantResults)
                                    // to handle the case where the user grants the permission. See the documentation
                                    // for ActivityCompat#requestPermissions for more details.
                                    return;
                                }
                                getApplicationContext().startActivity(callIntent);
                            }

                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

                        }
                    });
            }
        }

    public static Intent makeNotificationIntent(Context context, String msg) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(context, MainMenuActivity.class);
        intent.putExtra(NOTIFICATION_MSG, msg);
        return intent;
    }
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Buddy!! Works like a charm

Comment: My pleasant, bro :)

Comment: If possible can you answer this question as well? I did the same as you suggested, but it is not working for me on Android 10. [Click here for the question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/61478154/5716010)